# How to execute a remote page?

Tags: python

How do I exexcute python script found on a website?
For e.g. following seems to work. But is it the right way?

```
curl http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/UnionFind.py | python
```

I will like to know if I can import a webpage from python command prompt >>>

Comment: umm this seems awfully dangerous ... I mean someone could just intercept the request and place their own python script to do something rather unsightly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
>>> exec(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/UnionFind.py').read())
>>> uf = UnionFind()
```

Though, if you were really doing this, it would certainly make more sense to either `wget` or `curl` it to your local machine and then just import the module normally.

```
$ wget http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/UnionFind.py

>>> from UnionFind import UnoinFind
>>> uf = UnionFind()
```

Comment: The first solution seems better since it will work on both, windows and Linux.

Comment: Remember you have a huge security liability here. Any code that gets served from the URL will be executed as part of your application (or make your program behave differently if the download fails).

Also, the second approach doesn't have to be executed every time - you can just download the file and pack it together with your application (if the license allows that)

Answer (score 0):

The Python interpreter cannot download scripts by itself, so using a tool such as `curl` is an acceptable solution.