# execute a remote python script, locally with additional arguments

Tags: python, bash, shell, curl

I have a python script that resides on a remote server, under version control, and I'd like to execute it from my local shell.

I know that `curl https://remote.path/script.py | python` will work ([as confirmed here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016134/how-to-execute-a-remote-page) when there are no additional parameters.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to pass in additional command line arguments, e.g. `python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3`?

*I recognize this is may not be the most secure practice, but the script is pretty benign.*

Comment: are you using `argparse` or `optparse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check a [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/python) you will see that the `python` command takes either a script or the character `-`. The `-` argument instead of a script is used to tell the Python command that the script should be read from standard input. So using that all other arguments are know to be arguments to the script.

Used like

```
$ curl https://remote.path/script.py | python - arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 2):

`man python` would have answered your question:

```
   python [ -B ] [ -d ] [ -E ] [ -h ] [ -i ] [ -m module-name ]
          [ -O ] [ -OO ] [ -R ] [ -Q argument ] [ -s ] [ -S ] [ -t ] [  -u
   ]
          [ -v ] [ -V ] [ -W argument ] [ -x ] [ -3 ] [ -?  ]
          [ -c command | script | - ] [ arguments ]
```

Say:

```
curl https://remote.path/script.py | python - arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Example:

```
$ cat s
import sys
print  sys.argv[1:]
$ cat s | python - arg1 arg2 arg3
['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easily (and not recommended) you can just catch them in python using `sys.argv`

In file
    import sys

```
print sys.argv[1]
```

In terminal

```
python myfile.py foo

foo
```

If you do

```
print sys.argv[1:]
```

As another response suggested you'll get

```
["foo"]
```